# Executing Talend jobs with Rundeck

Tags: talend, rundeck

Hello dear community !

I am trying to use Rundeck to monitor and administrate my talend Jobs. I don't really get how to make this work...

I bluid the job in Talend which created a test_run.bat, a test_0.1.jar and 3 folders ( src, project_name, items).

I created a project and a Job in Rundeck, and in the job i inserted the directory to the test_run.bat file in the workflow section.

Of course it failed when I executed the job, I'm stuck...
I'd really appreciate if anyone who already worked with rundeck to execute Talend jobs could help me out !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. However there are more questions to ask before an answer can be given.

What is the full path to the bat or sh file of the job, on the server where it will be run?
Will the job be run on Windows, Linux, or another platform?
What is the script (rundeck) used to execute the job?
Is the same version of java installed there ?

What error did you get ?

Obvious things to check: 
Path and permissions